# react.js and commerce.js problem, cart value totalItems isnt working as it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, commerce

Im having problem displaying the total amount of items in the cart. The cart itself loads without a problem and items are also added without a problem. But when I try to get the total amount of items in the cart totalItems = {cart.total_items} and pass it on to the navbar.jsx file to be displayed, I get many errors. The app.js file is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { commerce } from './lib/commerce';
import { Products, Navbar } from './components';


const App = () => {

 const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
 const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

 const fetchProducts = async () => {
   const { data } = await commerce.products.list();

   setProducts(data);
 };

 const fetchCart = async () => {
   setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
   
 };
 

 const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
   const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

   setCart(item.cart);
 }
 


 useEffect(() => {
   fetchProducts();
   fetchCart();
 }, []);

 

 console.log(cart);

 

 return (
   <div>
       <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items}  />
       <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
   </div>
 )
};

export default App;
```

The main errors I get are: "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {totalItems}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." and "The above error occurred in the  component:". Im very new to react.js so any help would be appreciated.

Navbar.jsx code is as follows:

import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, IconButton, Badge, MenuItem, Menu, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';

import logo from '../../assets/mainlogo.png';
import useStyles from './styles';

const navbar = ({ totalItems }) => {
const classes = useStyles;

```
return (
    <>
        <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} color="inherit">
            <Toolbar>
                <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title} color="inherit">
                    <img src={logo} alt="Commerce.js" height="25px" className={classes.image} />
                        Project
                </Typography>
                <div className={classes.grow} />
                <div className={classes.button}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="Show cart items" color="inherit">
                        <Badge overlap="rectangular" badgeContent={totalItems}  color="secondary">
                            <ShoppingCart/>
                        </Badge>
                    </IconButton>
                </div>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
   </>
```

)
}
export default navbar

Comment: Can you add your Navbar code? How are you rendering the `totalItems` prop?

Comment: I guess you need to replace `const Navbar = (totalItems) =>` with `const Navbar = ({ totalItems }) =>` (explanation: you didn't destructure the `props` passed to the component)

Comment: I got the amount of products to show thanks to Your help, but the program still crashes when I add a product, hence when the number needs to refreshed. Error is as follows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total_items')".

Comment: That means your program hits `cart.total_items` while `cart` is `undefined`. The most likely culprit is an error in `handleAddToCart`, my guess is `item.cart` is undefined, this sets `cart` to `undefined` which then causes the error.

Comment: I looked around and tried different ways to fetch the cart and add to the cart, but none worked, stuck on the same error. Do You have any ideas what could help?

Comment: Start with basic debugging: After `const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);` insert `console.log(item);`

Comment: Tried that with cart too, everything seems fine there, no undefined console logs from there. Maybe the useEffect() is broken somehow?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(item);`? Is it an object with a `cart` property and if so, what does the cart property look like? No, `useEffect` isn't broken, your code is.

Comment: I switched the setCart(item.cart); out with setCart(item); and everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

i believe we are working on the same project from youtube ,i also encountered this problem.

u should try adding ? after the item then adding .cart

```
setMyCart(item?.cart)
```

or you can just ignore the .cart it will work just fine.

every-time you face this undefined error you should work around it with ? or ternary such as this example:

```
 if (!myCart.line_items) return 'Loading...'   return (
     <Container>
       <div className={classes.toolbar} />
       <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h3" gutterBottom>
         Your Shopping Cart
       </Typography>
       {!myCart.line_items.length ? <EmptyCart /> : <FilledCart />}
     </Container>   ) }
```